# Perform function on all possible pairs of columns

Tags: r, function, loops

I am working with data that include raters (columns) who assign scores to students (rows). The data are structured similar to this:

```
rater.1 <-rep(seq(1:4),each=6)
rater.2 <- rep(seq(2:5), each=6)
rater.3 <- rep(seq(3:6), each=6)
rater.4 <- rep(seq(1:4), each=6)
rater.5 <- rep(seq(2:5), each=6)
rater.6 <- rep(seq(3:6), each=6)

ratings <- cbind(rater.1, rater.2, rater.3, rater.4, rater.5, rater.6)
```

I want to apply a function to calculate a value based on every possible pair of raters. So the value will be calculated for (rater.1, rater.2), (rater.1, rater.3), (rater.1, rater.4), (rater.1, rater5), (rater.1, rater.6), (rater.2, rater.3), (rater.2, rater.4), ... etc.

The order of the raters in the pair does not matter.

Here is a simplified example using a function that calculates the sum of the observed ratings within a pair:

```
pair.sum <- function(rater.i, rater.j){

 pairsum.ij = sum(rater.1) + sum(rater.j)

 return(pairsum.ij)  
}
```

I would like to create a vector of the results somehow labeled with the names of which raters are in the pair. I know that a loop of some kind is probably needed, but I am not sure how to structure it to obtain results for all possible pairs.

The actual data include more columns and rows, and the function is more complex. But I wanted to start with a simple example and see if I can figure out how to generalize this to the actual data. I am new to programming and appreciate your help!

Comment: I'm not sure you understand the `seq` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
N <- ncol(ratings)
myfun <- function(i,j,data) {sum(data[,i],data[,j])}
vals <- Vectorize(myfun, vectorize.args=list("i","j"))
outer(1:N,1:N,vals,data=ratings)

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]  120  120  120  120  120  120
[2,]  120  120  120  120  120  120
[3,]  120  120  120  120  120  120
[4,]  120  120  120  120  120  120
[5,]  120  120  120  120  120  120
[6,]  120  120  120  120  120  120
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is an error in the use of the rep() function (as @Pierre L mentioned before). So I changed the data generation codes.

You can see the sums of the pairs you want by using the matrix obtained in the output.

```
# raters' datasets 
rater.1 <- rep(1:4, each=6)
rater.2 <- rep(2:5, each=6)
rater.3 <- rep(3:6, each=6)
rater.4 <- rep(1:4, each=6)
rater.5 <- rep(2:5, each=6)
rater.6 <- rep(3:6, each=6)

# the dataset
ratings <- cbind(rater.1, rater.2, rater.3, rater.4, rater.5, rater.6)

# column sums
colSums1 <- colSums(ratings)
colSums1

# for loop
MatrixA <- matrix(, nrow = 6, ncol = 6)
for (i in 1:6) {
  for (j in 1:6) {
   MatrixA[i, j] <- sum(colSums1[i] + colSums1[j])
    }
}

# output
MatrixA
```